# Discard mesh zones from solidify modifier

Tags: modeling, mesh

I would like to discard some zones from a mesh from solidify modifier, but I don't know how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose which part **you want to solidify** by setting **Vertex Groups**.

1. Go to *Edit Mode* (<kbd>TAB</kbd>) and select vertices you want to solidify.
2. Go to *Data tab* and under *Vertex Group* section add ('+' sign) new group and choose *Assign* (with vertices still selected).

[image: First]

3. Go back to *Object Mode* (<kbd>TAB</kbd>) and add *Solidify* Modifier.
4. Under it's option choose created vertex group.

[image: Second]

5. Set *Thickness* and a little bit of *Factor* not to have Z fighting problem.